# Nodejs Buffer.from leaks program context

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is it a known bug that when `Buffer.from()` is used with strings, it reads outside the variable bounds?

I was having *very strange* behaviour on my backend, where when I would concatenate 2 buffers, it would read a variable's contents and things after it, like other variable contents.

The typescript MWE is:

```js
import fs = require("fs");

function concatTypedArrays(a: Uint8Array, b: Uint8Array): Uint8Array {
    const c = new Uint8Array(a.length + b.length);
    c.set(a, 0);
    c.set(b, a.length);
    return c;
}

function concatBuffers(
    a: Uint8Array | Uint16Array | Uint32Array,
    b: Uint8Array | Uint16Array | Uint32Array
): Uint8Array {
    return concatTypedArrays(
        new Uint8Array(a.buffer || a),
        new Uint8Array(b.buffer || b)
    );
}

const test_var = "this is a long string: 6caD764D996ceB0B6217a01C3ec29DDEc760286C97c28FCBFFdF0dc41CD2AE5A0BdcF36a7Cd29cfc99E118Ef0Be71b4Ba4c1dfdE5CeEAaafee3b93ea4eb20ED5ab99bd0aABd2BFd9bdAc1FdA962813D7CD558c9a0AAD4dD81988eaF6c1481bA8AAa731A87AF7DC0B90cB303CBB16122f8778a1c62F38f19Ff599c147c133fC9a9ba0e272de1bA9eD8b6DcC3bD84Ea8d8d0033CdE1d56aa8bcfb4d7dBFd3cF7e354642c026f6EbFb0f1D28Bb6778Ba4CCaaB15eD66fF6Bd428a3cf6C8dD1dBAb3bAbbA3FF7B1ce784473daD21eF45f7a08Eff4FF1Beae9ce4F69DdB1351Bb1d348A7b4aE2F21c9dF3DeAaA2bECF646e34Dbc7F18C3c28fcccAafbA5ACA9C3d8D240adB5C18Df99DcefbEdE1b27C7bd867364abB983eEa7cDC25B401df91ba8A8E776AD0f3a8Faa06bc1ECaF5B0dA0f633f9bf85B24A33c6cAFfF0eEc4BD68B99eBdc8Af258F90ebB049Eb8e9daD3AcbdA47a5Cd2BFFD4d3cbd26BA";

console.log(`test_var: ${test_var}`);

let blob = new Uint8Array(0);

const test_str = "a string";

blob = concatBuffers(blob, new Uint8Array([0x41, 0x20]));

blob = concatBuffers(blob, Buffer.from(test_str));
// blob = concatBuffers(blob, Buffer.alloc(test_str.length, test_str));

fs.writeFileSync("./test_f.bin", blob);
```

(complete project [here](https://github.com/Luctins/mwe-node-buffer-bug))

Changing the `Buffer.from` to `Buffer.alloc` solves the issue. Otherwise the output file contains the content of the other variable in scope. From my point of view (I usually do embedded and systems programming) I don't see a clear reason for this behaviour.

The expected output file contents is:

```
A a string
```

But I get:

```
A <around 200 bytes from the program's context> a string<around 200 bytes from the program's context>
```

Is that a known bug, or is it an issue with my implementation? (or something else entirely)

Comment: try this `blob = concatBuffers(blob, Buffer.alloc(test_str.length, test_str));` once

Comment: Might be useful to post your actual vs expected output. Your post is kind of dancing around what specifically is happening.

Comment: @CollinD yep, you're right. I've added it to the question.

Comment: @DavidTeo you mean before the `Buffer.from` statement? it works as I've said on the question. I'm intereted in understanding _why_ this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return concatTypedArrays(
    new Uint8Array(a.buffer || a),
    new Uint8Array(b.buffer || b)
);
```

When you pass a `Buffer` into that as you do in the `blob = concatBuffers(blob, Buffer.from(test_str));` call, you're using that buffer's `buffer` property (its underlying array) directly, without any regard to its `byteOffset` or `length`. But the buffer's contents may not start at the beginning of the underlying array, nor fill it entirely. From the [`byteOffset`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/buffer.html#byteOffset) documentation:

> When setting `byteOffset` in `Buffer.from(ArrayBuffer, byteOffset, length)`, or **sometimes when allocating a `Buffer` smaller than `Buffer.poolSize`**, the buffer does not start from a zero offset on the underlying `ArrayBuffer`.
>
> **This can cause problems when accessing the underlying `ArrayBuffer` directly using `buf.buffer`, as other parts of the `ArrayBuffer` may be unrelated to the `Buffer` object itself.**

*(my emphasis, two places)*

On my system, for instance, the underlying array is 8192 bytes and the buffer data starts at offset 16. This despite the fact that `test_str` is only 8 characters long. As a result, you're using garbage data that's in the buffer's underlying array.

Instead, you need to only use the portion of the `Buffer`'s underlying array that the `Buffer` is actually using, by respecting `byteOffset` and `length`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning the specifics of TypeScript and It seems like I have some talking to do with my colleague who implemented that /s

Comment: @Luctins - Glad that helped. FWIW, this wasn't a TypeScript thing, it was a Node.js `Buffer`/`Uint8Array` thing. :-)